# AdMob error with cocos2D

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a simple Cocos2D game and in my game I include the AdMob SDK. When I run my project with a simulator it runs ok. But when I use a device I get this

```
error /Users/developway/Desktop/The GardenerResources/AdMob/libGoogleAdMobAds.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest AdMob. If that doesn't fix it, remove armv7s as supported architecture from Build Settings.